# CMake forgets about pthreads after changes in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, boost, pthreads, cmake

I'm having an odd problem with CMake and Boost.

I have a static library project set up such that each part of the library ends up being a separate static library. They depend on each other in an intelligent way and everything compiles and works perfectly the first time.

Below is the final link command:

```
/usr/bin/c++   -O3 -DNDEBUG    CMakeFiles/apollo.dir/main.cpp.o  -o apollo -rdynamic ../../libapollo/io/libio.a ../../libapollo/theoretical/libtheoretical.a -lboost_system-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_thread-mt -lpthread -lz -lboost_filesystem-mt ../../libapollo/core/libcore.a ../../libapollo/src/liblibapollo.a -lboost_system-mt -lboost_thread-mt
```

However, if I change one of the CMakeLists.txt files inside the library (such as adding a new .cpp, or even just re-saving a CMakeLists.txt), on running make again, the final executable that depends on the library fails in the final link.

Below is the failing link command:

```
/usr/bin/c++   -O3 -DNDEBUG    CMakeFiles/apollo.dir/main.cpp.o  -o apollo -rdynamic ../../libapollo/io/libio.a ../../libapollo/theoretical/libtheoretical.a -lboost_system-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_thread-mt -lz -lboost_filesystem-mt ../../libapollo/core/libcore.a ../../libapollo/src/liblibapollo.a -lboost_system-mt -lboost_thread-mt
```

To my eyes, those link commands appear to be exactly the same, sans the -lpthread.

Does anyone have any ideas how to ensure pthread gets included each time?

I ran a diff against a linking cmake build directory and failing cmake build directory. There is a difference in the link.txt of the executable build directory (as described above). There is also a difference in the main Makefile.cmake file. The working build directory has the following lines:

- "/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeCCompiler.cmake.in"
- "/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeCCompilerABI-
- "/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeCCompiler.cmake.in"
- "/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeCCompilerABI.c".c"
- "/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake.in"
- "/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp"
- "/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake"
- "/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake"
- "/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerABI.cmake"
- "/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake"
- "/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake"
- "/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeFindBinUtils.cmake"
- "/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeParseImplicitLinkInfo.cmake"
- "/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeSystem.cmake.in"
- "/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake"
- "/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake"
- "/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCompilerCommon.cmake"
- "/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeUnixFindMake.cmake"

However, I'm not sure if these would make a difference. I imagine the results of these are cached.

Comment: If you grep the entire project, which makefiles mention `-lpthread`, and in which context?  My guess is that when your executable is rebuilt because its dependencies change it gets `-lpthread` added to the link libs, but when it gets rebuilt because a CMakefile changes the flag doesn't get added to the link libs

Comment: Hey Jon,

None of my code specifically requires pthreads, but I do indirectly through boost threads.

I just ran 'grep -e "pthread" -R release/' on both make directories and the only difference between the two greps is the absence of -lpthread in the link.txt

Answer (score 0):

After having no luck at web searches, I finally gave up and just manually added threads to the CMake requirements. This works well and now I don't have to rebuild the library every time I modify a CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
if (Threads_FOUND)
target_link_libraries (libapollo ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
endif (Threads_FOUND)
```